# How to get rid of gn gen error while building Chromium?

Tags: python-3.x, linux, ubuntu-16.04, chromium, ninja

I have tried to find the cause for this particular error, but I cannot really understand how to get rid of it.

```
k@k-virtual-machine:~/Documents/code/chromium/src$ gn gen out/Default
ERROR at //chrome/version.gni:114:11: Script returned non-zero exit code.
_result = exec_script("//build/util/version.py",
          ^----------
Current dir: /home/k/Documents/code/chromium/src/out/Default/
Command:python3 /home/k/Documents/code/chromium/src/build/util/version.py -f ../../chrome/VERSION -t full = "@MAJOR@.@MINOR@.@BUILD@.@PATCH@" major = "@MAJOR@" minor = "@MINOR@" build = "@BUILD@" patch = "@PATCH@"  --os linux
Returned 1.
stderr:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/k/Documents/code/chromium/src/build/util/version.py", line 267, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/k/Documents/code/chromium/src/build/util/version.py", line 256, in main
    output = BuildOutput(sys.argv[1:])
  File "/home/k/Documents/code/chromium/src/build/util/version.py", line 248, in BuildOutput
    values = GenerateValues(options, evals)
  File "/home/k/Documents/code/chromium/src/build/util/version.py", line 198, in GenerateValues
    values = FetchValues(options.file, options.official)
  File "/home/k/Documents/code/chromium/src/build/util/version.py", line 62, in FetchValues
    FetchValuesFromFile(lastchange_values, lastchange_filename)
  File "/home/k/Documents/code/chromium/src/build/util/version.py", line 29, in FetchValuesFromFile
    with open(file_name, 'r') as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/k/Documents/code/chromium/src/build/util/LASTCHANGE'

See //ui/gl/features.gni:8:1: whence it was imported.
import("//chrome/version.gni")
^----------------------------

See //BUILD.gn:35:1: whence it was imported.
import("//ui/gl/features.gni")
^----------------------------**
```

Comment: Welcome back to Stack Overflow! [Please don't post pictures of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/4518341). Instead, copy the text itself and use the formatting tools like [code formatting](/editing-help#code). For more tips, check out [ask]. For example, it might help to write a clearer title, something that says *what* error.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Modified the problem, please look into it.

Comment: Looks like the source code has not been synced properly. Run `gclient sync` and try again

Comment: @Asesh I tried running gclient sync but I got errors like this :                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         WARNING: Filesize:1556480 does not match Content-Length:2135262

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I fixed it with those steps:

1. Go to /src/build/util
2. run lastchange.py script (python3 lastchange.py LASTCHANGE.dummy)
3. This script will generate a new file with the name LASTCHANGE.dummy.committime
4. rename it to LASTCHANGE.committime
5. if you still getting a missing LASTCHANGE file, create a copy of LASTCHANGE.committime and rename it to LASTCHANGE

this should fix the error

Comment: That doesnt fix my error. I get this (2 lines down from previous error):

`File ".../chromium/src/build/util/version.py", line 30, in FetchValuesFromFile
    key, val = line.rstrip('\r\n').split('=', 1)`

It looks like it expects a key-value pair.

Answer (score 0):

You can manually create two files in src/build/util directory: LASTCHANGE, containing following code

```
LASTCHANGE=0
LASTCHANGE_YEAR=1970
```

and LASTCHANGE.committime containing

```
0
```

It should work then.