# GN not Working When Trying To Make Chromium

Tags: windows, windows-10, chromium, gn

gn is not working please tell me how to fix it if requires sdk's please tell me the number and where to get it my operating system is windows 10.

Every time I type `gn gen out/default` it shows an error.
Here is how it looks:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/chromium/src/build/util/version.py", line 266, in 
<module>
sys.exit(main())
File "C:/chromium/src/build/util/version.py", line 255, in 
main
output = BuildOutput(sys.argv[1:])
File "C:/chromium/src/build/util/version.py", line 247, in 
BuildOutput
values = GenerateValues(options, evals)
File "C:/chromium/src/build/util/version.py", line 197, in 
GenerateValues
values = FetchValues(options.file, options.official)
File "C:/chromium/src/build/util/version.py", line 61, in 
FetchValues
FetchValuesFromFile(lastchange_values, lastchange_filename)
File "C:/chromium/src/build/util/version.py", line 28, in 
FetchValuesFromFile
    with open(file_name, 'r') as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 
'C:\\chromium\\src\\build\\util\\LASTCHANGE'
ERROR at //chrome/version.gni:121:11: Script returned non- 
zero exit code.
_result = exec_script("//build/util/version.py",
      ^----------
Current dir: C:/chromium/src/out/Default/
Command: C:/src/depot_tools/bootstrap- 
2@3_8_10_chromium_26_bin/python3/bin/python3.exe 
C:/chromium/src/build/util/version.py -f ../../chrome/VERSION 
-t "full = \"@MAJOR@.@MINOR@.@BUILD@.@PATCH@\" major = 
\"@MAJOR@\" minor = \"@MINOR@\" build = \"@BUILD@\" patch = 
\"@PATCH@\" " --os win
Returned 1.
See //ui/gl/features.gni:8:1: whence it was imported.
import("//chrome/version.gni")
^----------------------------
See //BUILD.gn:36:1: whence it was imported.
import("//ui/gl/features.gni")
```

So today I wanted to make chromium but when typing in gn gen out\Default it gave me an error can anyone post an answer about specs on how to make gn work and ways to fix it if it requires any SDK please tell me the version and where you can get it. My operating system is windows 10.

Comment: ANYONE PLEASE HELP

Comment: Your question seems clear now.  But it can take time for people to notice your question and write an answer.  I'm afraid I don't know the answer, but I did find these, which seem related: [How to get rid of gn gen error while building Chromium?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74646033) and [Error gn gen on win10](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/g/chromium-discuss/c/9-clGIeN7bI).

Comment: did you run `gclient sync` from `src` directory? It's unable to find `C:\\chromium\\src\\build\\util\\LASTCHANGE` which I think will be downloaded when  you run that command along with other third-party libraries

Comment: Yes I Did At The Start And After